# Determine which project I'm in and which are available

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc

I think I'm connected to BigQuery via ODBC:

```
isql -v BigQuery
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

My odbc.ini file looks similar to this:

```
[ODBC]
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/root/odbc.error


[BigQuery]
# 1 = User Authentication
Email=someemail@blah.iam.gserviceaccount.com
KeyFilePath=/service.json
Driver=/opt/simba/driver/lib/libgooglebigqueryodbc_sb64.so
OAuthMechanism=0
Catalog=someproject
```

With this ODBC connection, I assumed I would connect to project `someproject`. However, when I try to query a table I get:

```
SQL> select * from `someproject.ua.ua_user_daily` limit 10;
[37000][Simba][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: Access Denied: Project someproject: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project someproject.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLPrepare
```

I wanted to know which projects are therefore available to me within the SQL terminal, but I could not find any command to do this.

How can I test my connection by looking at what projects I do have access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem you are facing deals with roles, you need to [grant the role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#grant-single-role) `bigquery.jobs.create` to the service account.
You can also add the role `bigquery.user` or `bigquery.jobUser` these two roles contain inside the role `bigquery.jobs.create`. Check [all BigQuery roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) that you can grant.

Additionally, if you want to use the same Service Account around multiple GCP projects see this [post](https://gtseres.medium.com/using-service-accounts-across-projects-in-gcp-cf9473fef8f0) to see how you need to set it up.

You can Run the following Command in Cloud SDK to see which projects does your service account have access to:

```
gcloud projects list --impersonate-service-account=<your-service-account-email-address>
```

This command requires Cloud Resource Manager API to be enabled and `resourcemanager.projects.list` permission in your Service Account.

Comment: Thank you Jose! I'm looking forwards to testing this out when back at work on Tuesday. Will update here how it goes.

Comment: Hi Jose. I tried updating the role of the service account(After some messing around in the UI) but my issue remains. Exact same error message

Comment: @DougFir CatalogId should be specified as the project which has the permissions for job creation. The driver will use the project specified by this property to create the job.
I tried this scenario " where the service account only has roles/bigquery.dataViewer in the host project, and roles/bigquery.user in the client project" and it seemed to work correctly when the CatalogId was the client project. It failed with the error when specifying the host project which is expected since it doesn't have create permissions.

Comment: Just solved this with a colleague. I was in the wrong area within the UI. I had to go to IAM Admin > Add and from this area add the corresponding roles and permissions. This solved my problem.